# Attempt of exploit the equation $1/\operatorname{rad}(n)=1/2-2\varphi(n)/\sigma(n)$ in the context of even perfect numbers, and a related conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

It is well known that the problem concerning even perfect numbers is to prove or refute if there are infinitely many of them. Few weeks ago I wrote the following conjecture, where $\varphi(n)$ denotes the Euler's totient function, $\sigma(n)=\sum_{1\leq d\mid n}d$ the sum of divisors function and $$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}p$$
is the product of distinct primes dividing $n>1$ with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$, see the Wikipedia [*Radical of an integer.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) The encyclopedia Wikipedia has the article for [*Dedekind psi function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_psi_function) (see [1]) $$\psi(n)=n\prod_{\substack{p\mid n\\p\text{ prime}}}\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right).$$

One can to find the Euler's totient function and the sum of divisors function in formulations of equivalences to the Riemann hypothesis, and the so-called radical of an integer is the famous arithmetical function that appears in the formulation of the abc conjecture.

**Conjecture.** *An integer* $n\geq 1$ *is an even perfect number if and only if* 
$$\operatorname{rad}(n)=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}-2\frac{\varphi(n)}{\sigma(n)}}.\tag{1}$$

I've cited this conjecture few days ago in MSE. My intention is to know if is it possible to get some statement about the problem concerning even perfect nubmers, if there exist infinitely many of their, using the equation or well if you can argue that seems that the equation $(1)$ isn't useful for this purpose.

> **Question 1.** Does possible to get an interesting statement about the infinitude of even perfect numbers, or a fact about their distribution, using this equation $(1)$ or invoking previous **Conjecture** (it is easy to prove that even perfect numbers $n$ satisfy the equation $(1)$)? **Many thanks.**

You can to invoke propositions about even perfect numbers and tools or conjectures from the analytic number theory (we can search and read from the literature those statements). I hope that this is a nice exercise for this site, any case I hope comments.

**Claim.** *Similarly, denoting the Dedekind psi function as* $\psi(n)$ *one has that even perfect numbers satisfy the equation* $\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\psi(n)}{\sigma(n)}=-\frac{1}{2\operatorname{rad}(n)}$.

> **Question 2 (Added).** Prove (or show what work can be done about it) or refute finding a counterexample that *if* $m\geq 1$ *is an integer satisfying* $$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}\frac{\psi\left(\frac{m(m+1)}{2}\right)}{m(m+1)}=-\frac{1}{4\operatorname{rad}(m)}\tag{2}$$ *then* $m$ *is a Mersenne prime.* **Many thanks.**

**I've added** this secondary question as a comparison with the first question (Question 1 can be paraphrased as if you can to exploit the equation $(1)$ to get some interesting/remarkable statement for even perfect numbers). The conjecture in Question 2 concerning to the equation $(2)$ is true for the segment of integers $1\leq m\leq 3\cdot 10^6$.

### References:

[1] Tom M. Apostol, *Introduction to analytic number theory*, Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics, New York-Heidelberg: Springer-Verlag (1976).

Comment: Perhaps you can use the fact that all even numbers are of the form $2^{p-1}.M_{p}$ where $M_{p}=2^{p}-1$ is a Mersenne prime.

Comment: @Wojowu: I recommend against assigning gender arbitrarily to users. Your comment assumes the OP is male, for which there is no evidence; allowing our implicit gender biases to have us default to male pronouns further worsens the problem of making mathematical disciplines unwelcome for women.

Comment: Many thanks Wojowu and @GregMartin , I am male and truly the best students in the degree of mathematics that I've studied were women. I hope that women get in next years the best goals in mathematics, they are our  stars!